# È corretta l'espressione "Avrei piacere di..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Buongiorno,
sono stato recentemente criticato per avere utilizzato l'espressione "Avrei piacere di..." rispetto a "Mi farebbe piacere...".

Per quanto ne so, il verbo "avere" può essere utilizzato con riferimento a sensazioni, stati d'animo o sentimenti come sinonimo di "provare" (ad esempio "avere freddo", "avere fame" o "avere paura") ed il piacere, in quanto "sensazione di diletto" può certamente essere "provato".

Posso continuare a guardarmi allo specchio anche se occasionalmente mi esprimo dicendo "Avrei piacere di trascorrere del tempo con te" rispetto a "Mi farebbe piacere trascorrere del tempo con te"?

Comment: Non ho tempo di mettere a punto una risposta completa, ma: 1) per quel che vale, a me non suona tanto strano; 2) e soprattutto non suonava strano a Goldoni, Mazzini, Gioberti, Papini etc. (come si può evincere frugando in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22avrei%20piacere%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_it&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22avrei+piacere%22&lr=lang_it&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1it&tbm=bks&start=0).

Answer (score 2):

Per quanto mi riguarda, "avrei piacere di" anziché "mi piacerebbe" è tecnicamente corretto, ma mi suona molto burocratico e formale. Per esempio, "Avrei piacere di invitarLa al ricevimento" è sicuramente preferibile a "Mi piacerebbe invitarla al ricevimento", che tra l'altro può addirittura sembrare dire "però non la invito..."

Comment: Guarda un po', a me invece "avrei piacere di" suona più colloquiale (quasi scorretto, a dirla tutta). Io userei "mi farebbe piacere".

Comment: A conferma di quel che dice mau, «*abbiamo il p. di comunicarle ...*, formula usata nel dare notizie per via epistolare» nella [voce “piacere” del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piacere1/), che poco prima dà un più generale «avere piacere di qualche cosa».

Comment: Quell' "il" per me fa molta differenza. "Aver piacere di" e "avere il piacere di" a me (ripeto, a me) suonano molto diversi.

Comment: @karoshi corretta osservazione, ma in effetti nella voce del Treccani citata da DaG l'espressione è presente anche senza articolo.

Comment: Nello scritto formale o nei discorsi seri vedo/sento spesso "abbiamo il piacere di", al di fuori di queste situazioni mai. 
Colloquialmente sento sempre "mi farebbe piacere" o "mi/a me piacerebbe". 

Senza articolo invece non l'ho mai sentito e mi suona strano, e infatti in Google Books escono principalmente citazioni da libri dell'ottocento....